# How connect GKE airflow to RDS?

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-rds, google-cloud-composer, vpc

I'm using GCP composer (which runs in GKE) to run some airflow dags, but the rds dags are timing out. I've already done some network settings like VPC, DNS and firewall rules as the composer's documentation recommends and the connection works, I've tested it on a simple VM, but the GKE cluster can't connect to RDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an IP address problem, even creating composer with VPC the address of the pods had a different range. To solve this, I just needed to access the console and go to the GKE settings, in the network section, I wrote down the IP addresses that are in "Cluster pod address range (default)" and "Service address range" and released these IPs in AWS

Answer (score 0):

By RDS you mean the AWS service ? If so your Composer cluster needs to be able to connect to the internet. I'm not sure how your setup is and which version of composer you are using 1 or 2 ? But have a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/configuring-private-ip). Maybe you need an Egress firewall rule to 0.0.0.0/0 (the internet) on the port on which RDS listens

Comment: I've already done this, so much so that GCE vms can connect to rds, only kubernetes that don't

Comment: I had an other look at the docs, it seems like by default the GKE cluster created is Private and has no outbound to the internet [1].

But there is a way to enable outbound to the internet using Cloud NAT [2]



[1] https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/private-ip
[2]https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/private-ip#public_internet_access_for_your_workflows

Comment: After your answer I tried using NAT and it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you deploy the Cloud NAT gateway to the same Region where you Composer cluster is ?

Comment: Yes, both are in us-east1

Comment: Maybe it's a Firewall issue on AWS side ? You can assign a Static IP for the Cloud NAT gateway and allow that IP to talk to RDS on the AWS side.